# Error while building application

Tags: objective-c

I have integrated library called RSTPClient for streaming now after adding this project I am getting below error so can you please help me out to solve this issue?

Undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RTSPClientSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-RTSPClientSession in RTSPStreamerViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Post your code. We can't help blindly. However, this threw up a whole pile of related results: http://www.google.com/search?q=_OBJC_CLASS_%24_

Comment: Here is the library link : https://github.com/dropcam/dropcam_for_iphone

Answer (score 1):

This probably means that your code is including the library's headers, but is not actually linking with libDropcam.a. Since the headers are included, your code that references those symbols are initially able to compile, but when the linker finally goes to try and connect the symbols to actual code, it is not able to.

Here's Apple's docs on how to correctly libraries files: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010155-CH17-SW1

When the modal dialog comes up to select a libary, select "Add Other..." then navigate to your libDropcam.a file.

Comment: Not getting success: I have added the RTSPClient.xcodeproj in my existing project and it shows the libRTSPClient.a file and still it shows below error:   Undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RTSPClientSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-RTSPClientSession in RTSPStreamerViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Also I have tried to link up libRTSPClient.a as you have posted above but same issue.